# sum-of-digits issue with program

Tags: sum, sum-of-digits

```
public class quersumme {

public static int quersum(int a) {

for(int summe=0;) {while (a>0) {summe=summe+a%10;}
}

return a;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
int Wert=123;
System.out.print(quersum(Wert));
}
}
```

Program has issues with the for loop. It shows an error in ";".
Thanks for helping.

Comment: What language is this? Look like Java?

Comment: Ask yourself what the point of this for loop is. I think this question requires a little more effort debugging and researching. What have you tried so far? SE is not a code debugging service, especially for code that probably doesn't even compile.

Comment: @clvrmnky is it even in a compilable language?  C#?

Comment: @Jeter-work well, that would be my point. I don't even care what language it is in, but the OP ought to, and the OP ought to know if this snippet runs or not and what it does or does not do.